# Generating data for MANET nodes location in a specific format using ns2 setdest

Tags: network-programming, simulation, ns2

I am following this [link](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/822/chp%253A10.1007%252F978-3-642-30630-3_15.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fchapter%2F10.1007%2F978-3-642-30630-3_15&token2=exp=1494662727~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F822%2Fchp%25253A10.1007%25252F978-3-642-30630-3_15.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Fchapter%252F10.1007%252F978-3-642-30630-3_15*~hmac=6e2af613f14166f1fc7d47c5682d2d83a2ae5d22527e7760b0b286df6db2f3ce)  and trying to implement the scenarios there.
So I need to generate  a data for MANET nodes representing their location in this format:

**Current time - latest x – latest y – latest update time – previous x –previous y – previous update time**

with the use of setdest tool with these options:
1500 by 300 grid, ran for 300 seconds and used pause times of 20s and maximum velocities of 2.5 m/s.

so I come up with this command

```
./setdest -v 2 -n 10 -s 2.5 -m 10 -M 50 -t 300 -p 20 -x 1500 -y 300 > test1.tcl
```

which worked and generated a tcl file, but I don't know how can I obtain the data in the required format.

Answer (score 0):

> setdest -v 2 -n 10 -s 2.5 -m 10 -M 50 -t 300 -p 20 -x 1500 -y 300 > **test1.tcl**

Not a tcl file : Is a "scen" / scenario file with 1,700 "ns" commands. Your file was renamed to "test1.scen", and is now used in the manet examples, in the simulation example aodv-manet-20.tcl :

```
set val(cp)             "test1.scen"        ;#Connection Pattern
```

Please be aware that time settings are maximum time. "Long time settings" were useful ~20 years ago when computers were slow. (Though there are complex simulations lasting half an hour to one hour.)

Link, manet-examples-1.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNR05CclpEdVdvQm8/view?usp=sharing

Edit: New example added → manet0-16-nam.tcl → → https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNR0ZuQ1l6YnlWRGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?
can you please tell me more explanation and how can I get the required format of data?

Comment: ? Not quite clear what you mean. If you mean "the fomat " of a specific file, please write the file name. .... Please download the manet-examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNR0ZuQ1l6YnlWRGc/view?usp=sharing ... and run the examples. And run the created [out].nam files to watch the animation. Then you are welcome to ask again.

Comment: I mean that my target is for each node  I want to output 
[Current time - latest x – latest y – latest update time – previous x –previous y – previous update time]
until the end of the simulation.

I don't know how to do so.